# Why can't I set the writable attribute using a property descriptor in Object.create()?

Tags: javascript, properties, attributes, descriptor, writable

I am new to JS and I wonder why this piece of code prints false. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any hint!

```
var x = Object.create(Object.prototype, {x:{value:3, writable:true, enumerable:true}});

console.log(x.propertyIsEnumerable(x)); //false
```

Comment: Why does your title ask about "writable" but your code tests for "enumerable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you missed the quotes:

```
x.propertyIsEnumerable('x')
```

See below:

```js
var x = Object.create(Object.prototype, {x:{value:3, writable:true, enumerable:true}});

console.log(x.propertyIsEnumerable('x'));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!